# Can the interior of a (non-empty) smooth manifold with boundary be empty?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary.

If Int$M=\emptyset$, then $M=\partial M$ would be a smooth manifold **without** boundary, and so every point of $M$ is an interior point. Thus we have $M=$Int$M=\emptyset$.

> Is my argument correct? In other words, if I have a non-empty smooth manifold $M$ with boundary, am I authorized to assume Int$M\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: I think you might be confusing boundary of a manifold with boundary of a topological space. As a topological space, the interior of $M$ is always $M$ itself.

Comment: The definitions I'm using are from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Second Edition). Here in the question, by interior and boundary, i'm referring to manifold interior and manifold boundary.

Comment: I apologize for not reading carefully at first. $\operatorname{Int} M=\emptyset$ if and only if $M$ is empty. Your argument might not work because the implication "$M=\partial M$ implies $M$ is a manifold without boundary" might not be true. A better way to argue is to assume $M$ is non-empty and take a boundary point $x\in M$ so that it has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a half open ball, and pick an interior point in the half ball. This will give an interior point of the manifold $M$.

Comment: @lEm Thank you for your answer :)  I agree with your argument :) Just one question: why  the implication "$M=∂M$ implies $M$ is a manifold without boundary" might not be true? I kwno that if $M$ is a smooth $n$-manifold with boundary, then it is always the case that $\partial M$ is a smooth $(n-1)$- manifold without boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is unusual, but correct. You invoke two well-known facts:

1. Each manifold with boundary $M$ can be written as $M = \text{Int}M \cup \partial M$, where $\text{Int}M \cap \partial M = \emptyset$.
2. $\partial M$ is always a manifold without boundary.

However, to *prove* 1. and 2. you need to consider charts as in IEm's comment. This makes clear that no boundary point can exist without interior points.

Comment: Thank- you both! :) @Paul Frost Can you please give a look at my question in the comment, here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301767/diffeomorphisms-between-subsets-of-mathbbrn ?