# What can I say from "Diffeomorphisms of subsets of manifolds"

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

From the second section of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20diffeomorphism%20is,and%20its%20inverse%20are%20differentiable.) page on "Diffeomorphisms", I understand what is the diffeomorphisms of **subsets of manifolds**.

Now suppose the subset X of the manifold M with the subset Y of the manifold N. $X$ and $Y$ satisfy the diffeomorphisms of subsets of manifolds.

I find one helpful answer:

[Diffeomorphisms between subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301767/diffeomorphisms-between-subsets-of-mathbbrn)

Could I derive some other properties?

Let's say if X is $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{+}$ and $M = N = \mathbb{R}^{10}$, can I say something on Y (regularity or smoothness)?

You can assume any extra condition, but not on Y.
Any idea is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Diffeomorphisms are isomorphisms in the category of differentiable manifolds, and so preserve all 'relevant' properties.  For example, they preserve dimension … so, if $M = \mathbb R^{10}$ and $N = \mathbb R^8$, then there are no diffeomorphisms $M \to N$.  (This is called [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).)

Comment: You are right, there is no diffeomorphism between M and N. But in this case, we are talking about X and Y which are the subsets of M and N respectively. What can we say on that?

Comment: If you just mean that they are diffeomorphic on their own, with no conditions on extension to the ambient manifolds $M$ and $N$, then $M$ and $N$ are irrelevant.  For example, it makes no real sense to ask whether $Y$ is smooth; if it isn't smooth, then you can't have a smooth diffeomorphism to it.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the wiki page again. @LSpice

Comment: One of the statements you've written is just wrong. Take $M=\Bbb R$, $N=\Bbb R^2$, $X=M$, $Y=\{(x,0)\}\subset N$. Then the map $f\colon X\to Y$, $f(x)=(x,0)$, is a diffeomorphism. However, $X$ is open in $M$ and $Y$ is most assuredly not open in $N$. You have to be careful about having a diffeomorphism $M\to N$ versus a diffeomorphism $X\to Y$.

Comment: Thank you, I see where I did wrong! @TedShifrin